# How can we add element to map<int,int>... so that they are stored in non increasing order in map

Tags: c++11, stl, c++14, c++17

How can I make `std::map<int,int>` sorting values in non increasing order ?

```cpp
map<int,int> mp;
  
mp[5]=7; // {5->7}
mp[3]=9; // {5->7,3->9}
mp[4]=9; // {5->7,4->9,3->9}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
  std::map<int, int, std::greater<int>> mp; 
  mp[5] = 7;
  mp[3] = 9;
  mp[4] = 9;

  for (auto [k, v] : mp)
  {
    std::cout << "\n" << k << "->" << v;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Which prints:

```
5->7
4->9
3->9
```

We used `std::greater<int>` instead of default `std::lesser<int>` see [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

---

Also please note that you can also iterate over reverse order using a `reverse_iterator` (the `rbegin()/rend()` methods):

```
  auto iter = mp.rbegin();
  const auto iter_end = mp.rend();

  while (iter != iter_end)
  {
    std::cout << "\n" << iter->first << "->" << iter->second;
    ++iter;
  }
```

will print map (key,value) in the reversed order...

```
3->9
4->9
5->7
```